# What could I be getting stuck on when drilling into a stud?

Tags: drywall, wood, mounting

I was trying to drill a hole for bolts for a TV mount, using a 7/32 bit. About 1" in, the drill wouldn't go any further. It as was in the middle of where my stud finder indicated a stud (but it was about 2", so not sure if it was a real stud). But I tried to screw in the bolt with a wrench and it actually went in all the way (about 2.25" ). What do you think it was that the drill got stuck at, but I was able to wrench the bolt in? Do you think it's safe to leave the TV mounted with this bolt, or I should find a different spot?

Comment: Sounds like you went thru a wire guard. If you would have hit the wire you'd probably know by now though;)

Comment: Agree with paperstreet.  Wire guard or maybe a pipe guard. Good rule is that if your drill bits stops in a wall and you don't know why, you should pick a different spot to drill.